# Problem provisioning iPhone after 3.0.1 update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I used to be able to run my application on my iPhone that was running 3.0. After I updated to 3.0.1 I get the error:

No Provisioned iPhone OS Device is Connected.

I followed Apple's guide in the terminal:

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) / 
Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

but that didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you don't paste it into Terminal as you currently have it (and as Apple have it in their PDF). It should be one line, not two.

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

not

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /
Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

Comment: Dave you are correct. I was unable to accomplish this in the terminal because it was split into 2 lines instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Allow you need to do is duplicated the folder at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\)` and rename it to 3.0.1

Comment: While this will work, it would be better to do it with the symlink. See my answer below for the reason the original terminal command did not work

Comment: It's better to symlink the directory, as per the original instructions (which have a typo in the line). See Dave Verwer's answer.