# Problem provisioning iPhone with 3.0.1 after it worked before

Tags: iphone, xcode

After I installed iPhone OS 3.0.1 on my iPhone I followed the instructions on Apple's website (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225216/problem-provisioning-iphone-after-3-0-1-update)), created the symbolic links, and everything worked fine. That is, I could test my application on the iPhone.

Now it stopped working. I verified that the symbolic link is still there. I also tried deleting and recreating it and I also tried naming it 3.0.1 (7A400) instead of just 3.0.1. None of this worked, my iPhone is still showing up as "Could not support development" in the Xcode organizer.

Here are the contents of /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Device Support on my computer:

```
Macintosh:~ thm$ ls -la /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
total 40
drwxrwxr-x  12 root  admin  408 13 Aug 22:42 .
drwxrwxr-x   7 root  admin  238 22 Jun 20:43 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   11 21 Jun 20:17 2.0 (5A345) -> 2.0 (5A347)
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  admin  170 21 Jun 20:17 2.0 (5A347)
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   11 21 Jun 20:17 2.0.1 (5B108) -> 2.0 (5A347)
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   11 21 Jun 20:17 2.0.2 (5C1) -> 2.0 (5A347)
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  admin  170 21 Jun 20:17 2.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    3 21 Jun 20:17 2.1.1 -> 2.1
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  admin  170 21 Jun 20:17 2.2
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  admin  170 21 Jun 20:17 2.2.1
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  admin  170 21 Jun 20:17 3.0 (7A341)
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   12 13 Aug 22:42 3.0.1 -> 3.0 (7A341)/
```

I wonder if this is caused by my recent upgrade to Mac OS 10.5.8? I'm not sure whether I tested anything on the iPhone after the upgrade.

Did anybody else have a similar problem? Any ideas what might be causing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting with the simple stuff.  First, have you tried restarting xcode, your Mac, and the iPhone?

Comment: I restarted Xcode each time after I've played with the symlinks, I've unplugged the iPhone a few times and I restarted the computer. None of that helped. Your last idea, though, restarting the iPhone, did the trick :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this? Work for me.

http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.0__final/iphone_os_3.0.1_advisory.pdf